# Is Webcam Support Currently Possible With Pidgin and How?

Tags: webcam, instant-messaging, windows-live, yahoo-messenger

Can Pidgin currently support any kind of webcam, and if so, for what protocols, how and on what platforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No, not yet.](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/34)

Comment: 2.6.1 adds XMPP Voice and Video support (but not on Windows yet).